# Make text appear on the side when hover

Tags: html, css, text, hover

I am using for the first time this forum, so if I am missing some crucial elements let me know.

My goal: I am trying to create 4 clickable image (in a box layout) in which when the mouse goes over, I would like a slight animation to show an icon on the image AND i want at the same time, a descriptive text that would appear on its side of the image.

My situation: I have the images set up in the dimension I want, and the little animation.

My problem: I have tried many, many things, but can t managed to make the text appear on the side of the image when the mouse hovers on the image.
Here is the Html:

```
<div class="video-container">


<a href="" class="thumb-unit" style="background-image: url(/assets/img/video/thumb1.jpg)">

<div class="thumb-overlay">

    <strong>PLAY</strong>

</a> </div>
```

(above structure 4 times) 
And here is the css:

```
.videos
background: #e1f3f6

h3
    margin: 0
    text-align: center 
    font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif 
    letter-spacing: 1em 
    color: #deb75c  
    padding-top: 70px 
    font-weight: 300


.video-container

max-width: 930px 

margin: 0px auto
padding-top: 88px 
padding-bottom: 70px


+clearfix

.thumb-unit




    overflow: hidden
    display: block
    width: 50%

    position: relative 
    padding-top: 20%

    background: pink
    float: left

    background: 

        position: center center 
        repeat: no-repeat 
        size: cover







    .thumb-overlay


        +position(absolute, 100% 0px null 0px)
        height: 100%
        background: fade-out(#6693b0, 0.3)
        +transition
        text-align: center
        strong 
            padding: 30px 
            display: block
            Color: white 
            font-weight: 400
            text-transform: uppercase
            font-size: 17px

        background:
            image: url(/assets/img/icon/play.png)
            position: center 70px
            repeat: no-repeat
        h4
            border: 2px solid red
            position: absolute!important
            width: 300px!important
            right: 300px!important
            visibility: visible!important!important





    &:hover .thumb-overlay 
        +position(absolute, 0% 0px null 0px)
```

as you can see, the code reflects my current situation. 
If you have any insights, thank you very much!!!

Comment: Can you add many many things you've tried to http://jsfiddle.net and update your question with fiddles?

Comment: hi! what is a fiddle?
(Im very new to html and css so i don t have all the basics settled down..)

Comment: This 'fiddle' http://jsfiddle.net/yc3bcLr9/2/ should get your started.

Answer (score 0):

i have slightly adjusted your code, not sure what else is on your page but hopefully this will make sense and you can add it into your code.

```
<div class="video-container">
        <a href="#">
            <div style="background-image:url('Thumb.jpg');">
                <strong>PLAY</strong>
            </div>
            <div>
                This is the display text you want to display.
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
```

and the css

```
.video-container
{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin: 5px;
    float:left;
}
    .video-container > a > div:nth-child(1)
    {
        height:100px;
        width:100px;
        float:left;
    }
    .video-container > a > div:nth-child(2)
    {
        display:none;
        height:100px;
        width:100px;
        margin:-100px 0px 0px 100px;
        float:left;
    }
    .video-container > a:hover > div:nth-child(2)
    {
        display:block;
    }
```

i think it works how you want, its hard as not sure what the other code on your page is etc. i have changed some dimensions to make it a bit easier to work with. any comments on this will be greatfull